# XML pattern value

Tags: regex, xml

I know this is probably a stupid question but I've just received a document that specifies the XML document (format, etc) and I just wanted to verify that this is in fact actually what I think it is....

an integer

```
<xs:simpleType name="ThreeDigitNumbers">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
        <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{0,1}[0-9]{0,1}[0-9]{1}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
```

I have a field with the following type....

```
type="ThreeDigitNumbers"/>
```

Does this basically mean that it can be but doesn't have to be up to 3 numbers. Since this actually is supposed to be a value in a combobox - I'm assuming anything between 0-999?

Complete noob when it comes to XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more a regex question.The regex could be simplified to `[0-9]{1,3}`.
It's not **only** 0-999, number could also starts with zeros, like 000, 001, 010.
You can test which values you can use here: https://regex101.com/r/ic7kme/1

The regex basically means the following:

```
[0-9]{0,1} # zero or one digit
[0-9]{0,1} # zero or one digit
[0-9]{1}   # one digit
```

Comment: i guess my questino is based on the type given - does it have to be 3 digits always? so if it is 1 then it has to be 001. If i type in 1, 12, 123 it shows that it's a FULL MATCH

Comment: **1** and **01** and **001** will be valid value.

Comment: It strikes me as pretty crass and user-unfriendly to allow the number 1 to be input as 01 or 001 but not as 0001, but that's exactly what this schema author has chosen to do.